# Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'UInt32' operands

Tags: ios, swift, uint32

Here is my code.

```
var frameCount = INT_MAX
...

let totalSize: UInt32 = 4096
let itemSize: UInt32 = 64
frameCount = totalSize / itemSize
```

I get "Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'UInt32' operands" error message.
Is it really impossible or what did I miss?

Comment: `frameCount` is not a `UInt32` ;)

Comment: Why do you pre-set the variable? Just `let frameCount = totalSize / itemSize` and the compiler works it out.

Comment: @johnelemans: That is not correct. Swift can do integer division (and the result is truncated to an integer as in many other languages like C).

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading. `INT_MAX` is defined as

```
public var INT_MAX: Int32 { get }
```

so with

```
var frameCount = INT_MAX
```

`frameCount` is defined as a variable of type `Int32`.
The result of the division `totalSize / itemSize` is a `UInt32`
however, and Swift does not implicitly convert types.

You can fix that by changing the initial definition to

```
var frameCount = UINT32_MAX
```

or perhaps simpler, let the compiler infer the type:

```
let totalSize: UInt32 = 4096
let itemSize: UInt32 = 64
let frameCount = totalSize / itemSize
```

If you need the result as a signed integer then you have to
convert it explicitly, e.g.

```
let frameCount = Int32(totalSize / itemSize)
```